# Can the ActionBar drop-down navigation list control be disabled?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm using a navigation control in the ActionBar to provide a drop-down list. I would like to disable selection of the drop down list under certain circumstances.

My layout for the closed view of the spinner adapter has a `TextView` wrapped in a `LinearLayout`. The best I've come up with is overriding `getView` in my spinner's adapter and making both the `LinearLayout` and `TextView` non-clickable and disabled. This has the effect of greying out the text but it can still be selected.

**Edit** I appreciate that I can hide the list but this is not what I want to do. Furthermore I have returned false in the methods which check if one or all items are enabled but this does not work.

Trying to get this working with Honeycomb on a Xoom. Thanks in advance. Peter.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to prevent selection of anything in the list navigation mode, call `setNavigationMode(NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD)` and get rid of it entirely until you are ready for it to be used again.

If you want to prevent selection of specific items in the list navigation mode, have your `SpinnerAdapter` implement `areAllItemsEnabled()` to return `false` and implement `isItemEnabled()` to return `true` or `false` as needed -- I haven't tried this, but in theory it should work.

Comment: Setting the various enabled methods to return false does not work. I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @PJL: Then I suspect that what you want is not possible.

Comment: i used this code to hide/show the list when user clicks on thesearchWidget, otherwise it would resize my list ruining layout :)

Comment: I'd like to briefly point out that the `areAllItemsEnabled()`/`isItemEnabled()` solution does work for ActionBarSherlock.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom view in your ActionBar like so:

```
    ViewGroup customFilterBrowse = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.component_cancellable_progressbar, null);       
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setCustomView(customFilterBrowse);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

You can make the custom view do whatever you want (You can create a Spinner component which you disable in certain circumstances for instance).

HTH

Comment: thanks. Not working in this area any more (no longer a requirement) but will try this out sometime with the view to accepting the answer.