# android pass bundle with search

Tags: android, android-intent, android-searchmanager

Hello i am using android 3.0 **search widget**(not the search mode), the problem is i need to pass some parameters along with the search word.

Android isn't calling any of these

```
    searchManager.setOnDismissListener( new OnDismissListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDismiss() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.v(MyApp.TAG, "on dismiss search");

            }
        });

        searchManager.setOnCancelListener( new OnCancelListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.v(MyApp.TAG, "on dismiss cancel");

            }
        });

@Override
    public boolean onSearchRequested() {
        Bundle appData = new Bundle();
        appData.putLong("listino_id", this.listino_id);
        this.startSearch(null, true, appData, false);
        return true;
        // return super.onSearchRequested();
    }
```

I need my activity to **NOT** be singleOnTop,
here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity android:name=".activity.ListinoProdottiActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">


             <!-- Receives the search request. -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                <!-- No category needed, because the Intent will specify this class component-->
            </intent-filter>

                   <!-- enable the base activity to send searches to itself -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
              android:value=".activity.ListinoProdottiActivity" />


            <!-- Points to searchable meta data. -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                       android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

        </activity>
```

Here is my searchable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
     />
```

Comment: When you don't pass the extra parameter does it work?

Comment: i can't pass the extra parameter, since i can't use any "hook" to add parameters to the Intent, none of those 3 functions get called

Comment: Please paste the content of @xml/searchable.

Answer (score 6):

pass data with bundle in Search Widget:

**layout/main.xml** :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/hello" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button" android:text="test"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**layout/searchable.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/search_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" 
    android:searchMode="showSearchLabelAsBadge"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"
    android:voiceLanguageModel="free_form"
    android:voicePromptText="@string/search_invoke"
    android:searchSuggestSelection=" ? "
/>
```

**values/strings.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="hello">Hello World, SearchTest!</string>
<string name="app_name">Searchtest</string>
<string name="search_label">Search Test</string>
<string name="search_hint">1234</string>
<string name="search_invoke">234</string>
<string name="search_query_results">544545</string>
</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml** :

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".SearchWidgetExampleTest" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                       android:value=".ResultActivty" />
        </activity>

         <activity android:name=".ResultActivty"
                  android:label="@string/search_query_results">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.SAMPLE_CODE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                       android:resource="@layout/searchable" />
        </activity>
    </application>
```

**ResultActivty.java**:

```
package org.imranandroid.TestSearchexmp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ResultActivty extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Bundle bundled= getIntent().getBundleExtra(SearchManager.APP_DATA);
        Long ttdata=bundled.getLong("listino_id");
        Toast.makeText(this, ttdata.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**SearchWidgetExampleTest.java** :

```
package org.imranandroid.TestSearchexmp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SearchWidgetExampleTest extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onSearchRequested();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onSearchRequested() {
        Bundle appDataBundle = new Bundle();
        appDataBundle.putLong("listino_id", 4434724724L);
        startSearch("imran", false, appDataBundle, false);
        return true;
    }
}
```

***Happly Coding!!!***

Comment: thanks, it works as normal search, but it does not use the search WIDGET, as in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingSearchWidget or as in see screenshot here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588810/how-to-hide-unhide-the-actionbar-list-on-android-3

Answer (score 1):

when querying by searchview ( searchable || searchview widget ) 
you can pass parameter to searchActivity ( searchResultActivity ) 
by define your own OnQueryTextListener like this.

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            Intent searchIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchResultsActivity.class);
            searchIntent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, query);
            searchIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
            startActivity(searchIntent);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have hard coded strings for `android:hint` or `android:label` in res/xml/searchable.xml. They must be string resource ids.

Answer (score 0):

If your calls is syncronic(you perform one search request and waiting for response and don't perform any search request until you got your response) then it's easy.

Just create a helper static class to do it for you.

Some thing like this:

```
public static Bundle myStaticClass;
.
.
.
myStaticClass.putString(key, value);
callSearch();
.
.
.
afterSearchResponse();
String value = myStaticClass.get(key);
```

Comment: You asked about passing data, so this is how you can do it, if I misunderstand you please edit your question to be more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the follow

in Menu

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_al_ayats, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    Bundle appData = new Bundle();
    appData.putString("hello", "world");

    searchView.setAppSearchData(appData);

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return true;
}
```

and in your search result activity put the below

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_search_result);

    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String extrastring=intent.getBundleExtra(SearchManager.APP_DATA).getString("hello");
        //use the query to search your data somehow
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(extrastring);
    }
}
```