# Android - How to open standard search dialog?

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

I need to open the search dialog (it's opening, for example, when I click on standard search widget).

Comment: see this full example of search dialog [android pass bundle with search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700391/android-pass-bundle-with-search/9752578#9752578) may be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#InvokingTheSearchDialog) (Invoking the search dialog)
 should help (linked to a certain part of the page, but all of it is relevant).

Answer (score 1):

The search widget is a Google app and is non standard. The standard search dialog can be seen in the Twitter app or <s>Android Market</s> Play Store.

In HoneyComb and later the dialog has turned into a widget on the ActionBar.
Here's the developer's guide to search http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html