# SearchView in my application doesn't seem to be working

Tags: android, searchview

I have implemented the following code but my SearchActivity::OnCreate is not getting called.  Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kace.SearchTest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" android:value=".SearchActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".Search_testActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SearchActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.SAMPLE_CODE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**/res/xml/searchable.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/description" >
</searchable>
```

**SearchActivity.java:**

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            int q;
            q = 10;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    }

}
```

Comment: you have put multiple android.intent.action.MAIN,are you intentionally putting it, that means you have 2 starting activity

Comment: Hi RiNxX, With or without the android.intent.action.MAIN, it's not functional.  I copied this from Android Samples in the SDK...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot get searchview in actionbar to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699206/cannot-get-searchview-in-actionbar-to-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!  In the onCreate method of my main activity (Not the search activity), I added the following lines:

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
SearchableInfo searchableInfo = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());

SearchView sv = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.searchView1);
sv.setSearchableInfo(searchableInfo);
```

Comment: Have You looked at offical docs? http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html

Answer (score 15):

Android guides explicitly says:

```
// Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

Which is in your case NOT TRUE. Because you don't want to search in MainActivity but in SearchableActivity. That means you should use this ComponentName instead of getComponentName() method:

```
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(this, SearchableActivity.class);
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(cn));
```

Comment: Android should use your second snippet as that seems to work in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

Update your **AndroidManifest.xml** as:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Search_testActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
                <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" android:value=".SearchActivity"/>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SearchActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.SAMPLE_CODE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                   android:resource="@layout/searchable" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

put searchable layout in layout/ instead of  /res/xml/:
**layout/searchable.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/description" 
    android:searchMode="showSearchLabelAsBadge"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"
    android:voiceLanguageModel="free_form"
    android:voicePromptText="@string/search_invoke"
    android:searchSuggestSelection=" ? "
/>
```

For more working example see my answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700391/android-pass-bundle-with-search/9752578#9752578)

And

You can download working example from [SearchWidgetExample](https://hotfile.com/dl/156536457/0acb659/SearchWidgetExample.rar.html)

Comment: Thank Imran for the response.  However, making your changes still does not solve my problem :(  I did download the SearchWidgetExample and it did work correctly.  However when I put into the main.xml layout a SearchView widget, the ResultActivity::onCreate java method never got called.  Which is what I'm seeing with my app.

Comment: One more thing:  I am using SDK level 14 and running on my Nexus phone with Android 4.0.2.  Not sure if this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `default_searchable` setting under your "source" activity:

```
<meta-data
  android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
  android:value=".SearchActivity" />
```

In short, you need `default_searchable` setting for the "source" activity and `searchable` setting for the "search result" activity (your SearchActivity class).